# Iterate over mixed type slice

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I need to have different types of structs in a slice. But I can't access the field values of each struct.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type X struct {
    Type string
    Num  int
}

type Y struct {
    Type string
    Num  int
}

type Z struct {
    Type string
    Num  int
}

func main() {
    var items []interface{}
    x := X{Type: "X-type", Num: 1}
    items = append(items, x)

    y := Y{Type: "Y-type", Num: 2}
    items = append(items, y)

    z := Z{Type: "Z-type", Num: 3}
    items = append(items, z)

    for _, item := range items {
        fmt.Println(item) //{X-type 1} {Y-type 2} {Z-type 3}
        //fmt.Println(item.Num) // item.Num undefined (type interface{} has no field or method Num)
        //fmt.Println(item.Type) // item.Type undefined (type interface{} has no field or method Type)
    }
}
```

How can I access the individual fields for each type of struct?

Comment: See also [Type Assertions](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15) and [Type Switches](https://go.dev/tour/methods/16) in the [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

**Use a [type switch](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_switches):**

```
for _, item := range items {
    switch item := item.(type) {
    case X:
        fmt.Printf("X: %d\n", item.Num)
    case Y:
        fmt.Printf("Y: %d\n", item.Num)
    case Z:
        fmt.Printf("Z: %d\n", item.Num)
    default:
        // add code to handle unsupported type
    }
}
```

**Use the reflect package to access the fields by name:**

```
for _, item := range items {
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(item).FieldByName("Num").Interface().(int))
}
```

**Use interfaces:**

Add an accessor method to each type:

```
func (x X) GetNum() int { return x.Num }
func (y Y) GetNum() int { return y.Num }
func (z Z) GetNum() int { return z.Num }
```

Declare an interface:

```
type GetNumer interface {
    GetNum() int
}
```

Use the interface:

```
var items []GetNumer
x := X{Type: "X-type", Num: 1}
items = append(items, x)
...
for _, item := range items {
    fmt.Println(item) //{X-type 1} {Y-type 2} {Z-type 3}
    fmt.Println(item.GetNum())
}
```